# Solving Acceleration for Time with a limited velocity

Tags: excel, math, physics

I'm working on a calculator in Excel for interstellar travel times. I'm currently solving an equation for Acceleration for Time to arrival like so:

```
=sqrt(distance*2/acceleration)
```

which seems to work fine for me, except that if I give it a large enough acceleration and long enough distance, I get a maximum velocity back that is higher than the speed of light.

**What I want to do is add in some limiting factor into the formula that limits the velocity to some number**, but I have no idea how to do this in the mathematics (disclaimer: I'm a writer and artist, so I suck badly at math). I think I need to integrate something like `V=min(C,d/t)` where C is the speed of light, but I don't know how to integrate that into my function. Since the rest of this works without having to chart out periods of time, I'd prefer a solution in the formula rather than some roundabout recursive chart trickery. Any ideas?

Comment: This question does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the help center.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The right solution is of course to use the relativistic equation for the velocity after "constant acceleration" (which doesn't exist when you get near the speed of light). I suspect you mean "constant apparent acceleration" (what the passengers in the rocket feel).  In that case, relativistically,

```
v = c * tanh(asinh(F*t/m*c))
```

Where

```
v = velocity
F = force
t = time
m = mass
c = speed of light
```

Then you can write `F = m * a` so `acceleration = F / m`

which you can write in Excel (after defining the constant C_ = 3E8 )

```
= C_ * TANH(ASINH(acceleration*time/C_)
```

This will initially give you linear acceleration as expected - then it will taper off and never quite reach the speed of light:

[image]

It seems to me that this equation is "the right one" for your particular application - you are not really trying to be super accurate, just have something that at least doesn't go faster than the speed of light, and transitions smoothly. In reality, what a rocket motor can do at these very high velocities, how the mass of the rocket is changing - all those things make the math a lot more complicated.

**update** if you want to achieve a result like the above but only have "distance" and "acceleration", we need to be a little bit tricky. Of course distance is something that depends on your frame of reference - it's different for the people in the rocket vs a stationary observer. So we are going to throw "real physics" out of the window for a minute and do something else.  The straight red line in my plot represents "how fast you would be going if you kept accelerating" - this is the velocity of your initial calculation.

You can convert that to the "real" velocity with a simple

```
limitedVelocity = C_ * TANH(ASINH(calculatedVelocity / C_))
```

This is more in keeping with the question you asked, and allows you to stay in the framework you had (where you know "acceleration" and "distance" - whatever those mean in your world.)

Relativity. Blows your mind.

Afterthought

An accelerating space ship is in a non inertial frame of reference. The clock on board runs at a different speed (slower) than the "clock in the universe". Inside the spaceship the distance to their destination appears to shrink (Lorentz contraction) as they go faster. All this means that the "real" calculation depends on factors and assumptions that were not explicitly stated in the question. But since this is about an "interstellar travel calculator" by a self-professed non-physicist I think it is better not to turn this into a second year Physics of General Relativity course.

Comment: Nice.. +1 for the relativity lesson.

Comment: Thanks very much for this, it's exactly what I was thinking, and I'm in the process of implementing it in my calculator. On the topic of time dilation, I've found a formula that can give me the time dilation aboard the ship given the time of a a stationary frame of reference, ``=sqrt(1-(velocity^/C^2))``, does that seem correct? It returns values that look alright to me based on the graph on wikipedia, leading to large (small, I guess?) time dilation numbers only when you feed it a velocity higher than about .9C.

Comment: Small typo in your expression - time dilation (gamma factor) `=SQRT(1 - (V/C)^2)` . You had an extra `^` in there (or one too few). Note - once you start thinking about "how long do the people in the rocket think the trip takes" vs "how long does everyone else think it takes" your head starts to spin. Doing relativity "right" is quite hard. But for your purpose these equations should be quite useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `IF` statement:

```
IF(logical_test, [value_if_true], [value_if_false])
```

As in:

```
=IF( sqrt(distance*2/acceleration) > C , C , sqrt(distance*2/acceleration) )
```

Comment: That was my thought, but I figured that if I did that, once I fed it a set of values that would be too high, it would "overfill" the graph, i.e. instead of accelerating at A, it would eventually act like the ship had been going the speed limit the whole time, instead of after it reached the limit by accelerating. Does that make sense or am I completely daft?

Comment: That depends on what you are really trying to do with the data.